# How can I change the values of an observable to be true or false?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

So I have this assignment to make a program that is checking the username.

Imagine there is a system that you can log in only if you type in "tester" as your username. There is an observable called username$ that keeps track of the user input and I want to create another observable, in which instead of "tester" will be true and instead of anything else false.

This is the visualization of the the [observables](https://rx-marbles-online.herokuapp.com/?marblescode=marble+user_provided_correct_username%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++source+a:+++++%2B--(tester)-(other)--(tester)-%7C%0D%0A++++operator+%3F%3F%3F:+%2B--(true)-(false)--(true)-%7C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&scale=100&theme=default)

I have written the following code, but obviously too long.

```
const userProvidedCorrectUserName$ = (
  userName$: Observable<string>,
): Observable <boolean> => {

  const trueElements$ = userName$.pipe(
    filter((userInput) => userInput === "tester"),
    mapTo(true)
  )
  const falseElements$ = userName$.pipe(
    filter((userInput) => userInput !== "tester"),
    mapTo(false)
  )
  const output$ = merge(trueElements$, falseElements$); 
  return output$
}
export { userProvidedCorrectUserName$ }
```

So my question is: How should I rewrite this without splitting the first observable and then changing its values? Is there a simpler operator to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you could just use `map(userInput => userInput === "tester")` on a single source Observab;e but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Or something like: `map(userInput => {userInput:userInput, val: userInput === "tester"})` to maintain the original data

Comment: I'm not sure how a stream of `booleans` is useful.... I suspect this might be an XY problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `map` operator and return the boolean from the string comparison.

```js
let userInput = "tester";
console.log(userInput === "tester");

userInput = "other";
console.log(userInput === "tester");
```

The following observable would `true` or `false` accd. to your condition.

```js
const userProvidedCorrectUserName$ = (
  userName$: Observable<string>,
): Observable<boolean> => {
  return userName$.pipe(
    map((userInput: string) => userInput === "tester")
  );
}
export { userProvidedCorrectUserName$ }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect opportunity to use the `map` operator provided by rxjs.  Here is a [basic example](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators#higher-order-observables) from RxJS:

```
const fileObservable = urlObservable.pipe(map((url) => http.get(url)));
```

The map operator allows you to map the values of an observable to a different type, so you can use it to create a boolean observable from `userName$`